# Keeping connection after removing/(change IP address) in security policies in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2

In AWS console we must specify actual rules in order make it possible to access EC2 instances from remote localizations.
I mean rules like opening some port or access from allowed IP addresses.

And it is working for me now.

I consider following scenario:

Let's assume that we have application A which maitain long running connection and everything is working because 
security rules are properly set. Now,

(a) someone remove rules allowing application A connect to EC2 instancs (so external IP address which is used by application A)
(b) at any point external IP address of machine used by application A change.

I consider if it is possible that connection established before occurence (a) or (b) keeps working? If yes, then how is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty basic explaination to your answers. Ofcourse, there's a lot more information on the matter, but I guess it is not of importance right now.

1. If you change a rule, let's assume it is a Firewall rule or AWS Security Group rule, the connection will terminate as the rule takes effect immediately.
   Simply put, you are sending a stream of information packet by packet, so when the change is detected the packets will no longer be receieved and you will no longer receive a response, i.e. the connection will terminate.
2. If you change your IP  and you are using TCP connections, which I assume you do, they will also terminate as TCP connections are based on IP:Port combinations, BUT if you are using DNS rather than just IP your traffic will be routed correctly, you might experience some downtime, but your service will get back working soon enough.

**EDIT**: As noted by Michael, the security group change doesn't cut off existing connections. The next time an attempt is made, it will block them.

Comment: You have no idea.

Comment: Hmm, what does that mean?

Comment: @AlexK *"the connection will terminate as the rule takes effect immediately."* I don't believe this is correct.  Security group rules only determine what new connections can be *established*.  Once established, removing the rule does not force already-established connections to fail.

Comment: You could be right,  I will test it and add a comment

Comment: You are indeed correct, this is only true for firewall

Comment: Don't know if it counts, but I tested it- created ec2, connected and changed the security group,  did not get disconnected.

Comment: [*"An existing flow of traffic that is tracked may not be interrupted when you remove the security group rule that enables that flow."*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#security-group-connection-tracking)  Note that the documentation suggests that rules allowing "all" may not conform to this behavior, since the connections may not be tracked.